# sort list consisting of numbers and string values

Tags: python, list

I don't whether it's possible at all but I have got a list consisting of many values like

```
list = ["0.75543 blue", "0.5454 red", "0.113424 blue", "0.9993233 red" and so on] and so on.
```

In other words I have values between 0 and 1 and two labels blue and red. When I click `array.sort()` it doesn't sort them properly as the values in the list are strings. I want to be able to sort the list based on the values only properly (independent of the label). Is that possible?

Comment: You mean, sort based on the numbers?

Comment: yes. I want to sort only on the numbers

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name since it's a builtin type and function.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can sort just based on the numeric value in the first part of the string. Just pass `sort` a key that extracts the number from each string.

**Demo**

```
>>> L = ["0.75543 blue", "0.5454 red", "0.113424 blue", "0.9993233 red"]
>>> L.sort(key=lambda l: float(l.split()[0]))
>>> L
['0.113424 blue', '0.5454 red', '0.75543 blue', '0.9993233 red']
```

Also, depending on what you're doing, you may find it easier to store the value-label pairs as tuples. Then, sorting is even easier (and arguably more intuitive):

```
>>> L = [(0.75543, "blue"), (0.5454, "red"), (0.113424, "blue"), (0.9993233, "red")]
>>> L.sort(key=lambda t: t[0])
>>> L
[(0.113424, 'blue'), (0.5454, 'red'), (0.75543, 'blue'), (0.9993233, 'red')]
```

Finally, please don't name your lists `list`; `list` is a built-in type and function in Python (see @2rs2ts's comment).

Comment: I have tried it but it says AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: @user3149650: what does your list look like? It works for the list in my demo, so I'm assuming yours is slightly different?